# Erro ao conectar banco de dados com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Estou com um código OOP em PHP, quando tento conectar com o BD aparece o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: operator in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastroDeAlunos\app.ado\TCriteria.class.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastroDeAlunos\app.ado\TConnection.class.php on line 46
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastroDeAlunos\app.ado\TConnection.class.php on line 46

#### conection.ini

```
host = ['127.0.0.1']
name = ['sistema_escolar']
user = ['root']
pass = ['']
type = ['mysql']
```

#### connection.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($classe)
{
    if(file_exists("../app.ado/{$classe}.class.php"))
    {
        include_once "../app.ado/{$classe}.class.php";
    }
}

$sql = new TSqlSelect;

$sql->setEntity('sistema_escolar');

$sql->addColumn('id');
$sql->addColumn('nome');

$criteria = new TCriteria;

$criteria->add(new TFilter('id','=','1'));

$sql->setCriteria($criteria);

try
{
    $conn = TConnection::open('connection');

    $result = $conn->query($sql->getInstruction()); 
    if($result)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $row['id'].'-'.$row['nome']."\n";
    }
    $conn = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print "Erro: ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";

}
?>
```

#### TCriteria.class.php

```
<?php
class TCriteria extends TExpression
{
    private $expressions;
    private $operators;
    private $properties;

    public function add(TExpression $expression, $operator = self::AND_OPERATOR)
    {
        if(empty($this->expressions))
        {
            unset($operator);
        }

        $this->expressions[] = $expression;
        $this->operators[] = $operator;
    }

    public function dump()
    {
        if(is_array($this->expressions))
        {
            foreach($this->expressions as $i => $expression)
            {
                $operator = $this->operators[$i];
                $result .= $operator . $expression->dump() . ' ';
            }
            $result = trim($result);
            return "({$result})";
        }
    }

    public function setProperty($property, $value)
    {
        $this->properties[$property] = $value;
    }

    public function getProperty($property)
    {
        return $this->properties[$property];
    }
}
?>
```

#### TConnection.class.php

```
<?php
final class TConnection
{ 
    private function __construct()
    {

    }

    public static function open($name)
    {
        if(file_exists("../app.config/{$name}.ini"))
        {
            $db = parse_ini_file("../app.config/{$name}.ini");
        }

        else 
        {
            throw new Exception("Arquivo '$name' não encontrado");
        }

        $user = $db['user'];
        $pass = $db['pass'];
        $name = $db['name'];
        $host = $db['host'];
        $type = $db['type'];

        switch($type)
        {
            case 'pgsql':
                $conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname={$name};user={$user};password={$pass};host={$host}");
                break;

            case 'mysql':
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname={$name}",$user,$pass);
                break;

            case 'ibase':
                $conn = new PDO("firebird:dbname={$name}",$user,$pass);
                break;

            case 'mssql':
                $conn = new PDO("mssql:host={$host},1433;dbname={$name}",$user,$pass);
                break;      
        }

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_MODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Um `var_dump` da variável `$db` no método `TConnection::open` retorna o que? Seu arquivo `ini` me parece mal formatado (não sei se o PHP aceita no modo como escreveu).

Comment: Tanto o connection.ini quanto o php.ini estão configurados

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Os erros são autoexplicativos.

O primeiro é erro de digitação. É só mudar na linha 16 para:

```
    $this->operators[] = $operators; //faltava um s aqui
```

O segundo é que a variável não existe porque não entrou em nenhum `case`. Tem que tratar esta situação porque ela pode existir. E provavelmente sua configuração está errada porque não especificou nenhum tipo. Então eu colocaria isto no final do `switch`:

```
default:
    throw new PDOException('Nenhum tipo de banco de dados foi selecionado');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/DefaultSwitch.php).

Mas ainda teria que arrumar a configuração no `ini`.

O terceiro erro é consequência do segundo.

Na verdade tem solução melhor mas teria que mudar muito sua aplicação.

Embora não vá causar problema na maioria das vezes p ideal é não usar `file_exists`. Deixe o erro acontecer ao acessar o arquivo, se for o caso, até gere a exceção que deseja. Mesmo que é uma ideia ruim gerar uma exceção desta forma. Mas não vou entrar em detalhes porque não é o foco da pergunta.

Mande imprimir temporariamente o valor das variáveis `$user`, `$pass`, `$name`, `$host` e `$type`. Você verá que elas estão sem valor ou com valores errados. Então você tem problemas com seu `ini`. De fato a maneira como está escrito é errada o mais correto provavelmente seria:

```
host = "127.0.0.1"
name = "sistema_escolar"
user = "root"
pass = "senha aqui"
type = "mysql"
```